# How do I convert a negative dollar value surrounded by parenthese to numeric?

Tags: r, readr

I have a `df` that has a column where the negative dollar values are surrounded by parentheses.  How do I convert the column into numeric for both positive and negative values?  `parse_number` works for positives, but doesn't account for parentheses representing negative values.

Sample DF

```
sample <- 
  tibble::tribble(
   ~id, ~dollars,
    36, "($0.3)",
  1890,   "$3.6",
  3298, "($0.1)",
  3448,   "$0.2",
  4616,   "$0.0",
  5409, "($0.1)",
  5751, "($0.1)",
  5942,   "$0.1",
  6316,   "$0.0",
  6589,   "$0.1"
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do what the question asks for.

```
as.numeric(sub("\\(", "-", gsub("\\)|\\$","", sample$dollars)))
# [1] -0.3  3.6 -0.1  0.2  0.0 -0.1 -0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1
```

Less readable but simpler, just one `*sub`.

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\(*\\$([[:digit:].]+)\\)*", "-\\1", sample$dollars))
# [1] -0.3  3.6 -0.1  0.2  0.0 -0.1 -0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1
```